# android app: see only markers or overlay on a google map and not the map

Tags: android, google-maps, google-maps-api-3, overlay, marker

android app: can I draw (markers and polyline) on google map when map is not visible? I use a google map, but I want see only the markers or ground overlay images there are on the map and I don't want see the map...
I am a beginner so thanks for help me...

Answer (score 1):

You can set the map to have no tiles by just setting the type to NONE:

```
map.setMapType(GoogleMap.MAP_TYPE_NONE);
```

when you have the object GoogleMap

Comment: thanks very match, with setting the type to NONE i see only markers and overlay on the map...Thanks!!!

Comment: You're welcome. Accept the answer if fits the request so others can understand is ok and benefit

Answer (score 0):

As the method getMap() is deprecated in [MapFragment](https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/maps/MapFragment.html#getMap()) and in [MapView](https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/maps/MapView.html#getMap()) You should draw the markers and polylines only when [onMapReady(GoogleMap map)](https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/maps/OnMapReadyCallback#onMapReady(com.google.android.gms.maps.GoogleMap)) method gets called. At this point of time you are having Map's object then you can add markers,polyline. You can't change map't visibility. You can change map type(Satellite, Hybrid or terrain) to suit your needs.